# How to get rid of "Abort trap: 6"

Tags: c, abort

Here is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char a[15],d;
    int month, day;
    char *m=&a[15];
    scanf("%s %s", m, &d); 

    if (strncmp(m,"January",7)==0) month = 1;
        else if(strncmp(m,"Febuary", 7)==0) month = 2;
        else if(strncmp(m,"March",5)==0) month = 3;
        else if(strncmp(m,"April",5)==0) month = 4;
        else if(strncmp(m,"May",3)==0) month = 5;
        else if(strncmp(m,"June",4)==0) month = 6;
        else if(strncmp(m,"July",4)==0) month = 7;
        else if(strncmp(m,"August",6)==0) month = 8;
        else if(strncmp(m,"September",9)==0) month = 9;
        else if(strncmp(m,"October",7)==0) month = 10;
        else if(strncmp(m,"November",8)==0) month = 11;
        else if(strncmp(m,"December",8)==0) month = 12;
        else {month =0; printf("invalid date");};

    day = atoi(&d);

    int months[] = {0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334};
    int days = months[month-1] + day;
    printf("%s %d is the %d day of the year\n",m, day, days);

    return 0;
}
```

All of the code runs correctly but then at the end of the program it gives me the error message Abort trap:6. I know this has to do with memory allocation, but I don't know what specifically is causing it.

Edit: Side note, for this code I can assume that the date will be typed in a correct format, e.g "Month Day" with the month always being a capital letter and an actual month, etc.

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Try adding some other tags to your question that gives it some context.

Comment: What the heck is `char *m=&a[15];` trying to do? it looks like you're intentionally corrupting memory. Reading an entire string into a single character `d` is also not going to end well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The abort trap occurs because `d` is a single character, but you attempt to store a string into it. `scanf` is able to read and convert numbers, so you could eliminate `d` and the `atoi` and just use `scanf` to read the day directly.

I should also point out that the line

```
char *m=&a[15];
```

points `m` to the **end** of the array. If you eliminate `a` and declare `m` as the array, then `m` can be used as a pointer to the beginning of the array.

The first few lines of your code should look like this

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char m[16];
    int month, day;
    scanf("%15s%d", m, &day); 

    if (strcmp(m,"January")==0) month = 1;
```

Side note: using `strncmp` is unnecessary (since both `m` and the constant string are well formed) and error prone (since you could get the length wrong). So the compares should be done with `strcmp`.

And as @JonathanLeffler pointed out in the comment, using `strncmp` would allow invalid month names to pass the comparison. For example,

```
strncmp( "Maybe", "May", 3 )
```

will return 0.

Comment: I agree with the primary diagnosis (`"%s"` and `char d;`), though the definition of `m` is also problematic. Also, `Maybe 13` and `Marching 2` would be acceptable dates with `strncmp()`.  Not to mention that the code does not yet validate the day of the month, so 0th, 32nd, and 99th of the month are all accepted.  That's probably because of the crash side-tracking the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First I tried running your code on my Linux box and had no issue however if I put in an invalid date for m I got an error pertaining to stack smashing which I believe is what you are experiencing.
As Raymond pointed out the following line is really really wrong.

```
    char *m=&a[15];
```

I may be getting this wrong but I believe this says, take the value from a[15] (which is invalid memory) and get me that address, then store it as m. Essentially you get a pointer to the address right after array a ends. Thus when you store something in m this is NOT memory that you have asked the OS for which leads to unexpected behaviour. I would suggest that you change that line to the following since it will work for you much better.

```
char m[15];
```